# How to remove the index label in visual studio designer while Tab Order is active in visual studio using C# in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, devexpress, tabindex

im using a xtraTabControl from devexpress and i have 10 tabs within.
problem is every tab contains at least 20 controls.

problem starts when i have to set the index of these in design of visual studio.

normally id do view > tab order and click on my controls in the right order to assign the Indexes to them in at least 1/10 of the time it takes to do it manually.

however this time it seems quite impossible.
[image: this is all i see ! and i have 20 controls in each tab (at least) behind these]

so long story short:
is there a way to make these labels disappear or give em transparency to be able to find and recognize the controls behind them to click the right ones?

or do i have to set the tab index for ALL the controls within the tabs manually... ?

Comment: That quite beyond any reasonable measure of hope of course.  Send a nastygram to devexpress, makes you feel better.  Refactoring the tab content into UserControls would be a way to get somewhere, doubtful you'll find it an acceptable approach.

Comment: Ive found out that devexpress has controls that automatically assign tab indexes to the child controls from top to bottom ,they are good. But sadly that wont solve my issue as i cant change the nature of the controls used in the forms ive been given... 